# How to align product name , price to center in magento 2 ? it have option in theme or change in code

Tags: magento2, product, luma-theme

[image]I have products in the page I need to centrer the product name and price?

I have an option to theme or change in the code?

Comment: which theme user and give the product page screen-shot.

Comment: Screen shot added

Comment: it code change only

Comment: can u help me to where the path is

Comment: pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css

Comment: it also has header path

Comment: what it also has header path?

Comment: Home page header menu

Comment: which css file i can change